# Clear function in my BlackJack game doesn't work?

Tags: python

I do have a small problem in my code: I do not know and cannot find anywhere how to use a function to clear the console at a certain point in my game. I use Pycharm, maybe it has to do with that.

Context: I have started learning from scratch 12 days ago.

```
import random
import ascii
print(ascii.logo)


#to make it easier, for ace we assign 11 and for each card with the value of 10, we just draw a 10.
cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

#here we draw our cards
mycards = [random.choice(cards), random.choice(cards)]
print(f"Your cards are: {mycards} current score:{sum(mycards)}")

#here we draw the dealer's cards, both public and secret one. we only show, of course, the public one.
dealers_1st_card = random.choice(cards)
computercards = []
computercards.append(dealers_1st_card)
computercards.append(random.choice(cards))
print(f"Dealer's first card is: {dealers_1st_card}")

#Bellow here I invented a few functions so they can help me with the process, make it easier. With these functions, I can
#recall it when I need it and make some kind of loop, which goes on for as long as the game requires.

def clear():
    """ Improvise, adapt, overcome"""
    print(100 * "\n")
def draw():
    if sum(mycards) == sum(computercards):
        print(computercards)
        print("It's a draw!")

def ace_check(mycards, computercards):
    for i in range(len(mycards)):
        if mycards[i] == 11 and sum(mycards) > 21:
            mycards[i] = 1
    for i in range(len(computercards)):
        if computercards[i] == 11 and sum(computercards) > 21:
            computercards[i] = 1


def stand():
    while sum(computercards) <= 16:
       drawcard =  computercards.append(random.choice(cards))
       drawcard
    ace_check(mycards, computercards)
    while sum(computercards) <= 16:
       drawcard =  computercards.append(random.choice(cards))
       drawcard
    print(f"Dealer's cards are: {computercards} current score: {sum(computercards)}")
    if sum(computercards) > sum(mycards) and sum(computercards) <= 21:
        print("You Lose.")
    elif sum(computercards) < sum(mycards) and sum(mycards) <= 21:
        print("You Win.")
    elif sum(computercards) > sum(mycards) and sum(computercards) > 21:
        print("You Win.")
    elif sum(computercards) < sum(mycards) and sum(mycards) > 21:
        print("You Lose.")
    else:
        draw()


def hit():
    drawcard = mycards.append(random.choice(cards))
    drawcard
    ace_check(mycards, computercards)
    print(f"Your cards are {mycards} current score: {sum(mycards)}")
    if sum(mycards) > 21:
        print("You lose")
        print(f"Dealer's cards: {computercards} current score: {sum(computercards)}")
    elif sum(mycards) == 21:
        print(f"Dealer's cards are {computercards} current score: {sum(computercards)}")
        if sum(mycards) > sum(computercards):
            print("You win!")
        else:
            draw()
    elif sum(mycards) <= 21:
        hit_or_stand = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass: ")
        if hit_or_stand == "y":
            hit()
        elif hit_or_stand == "n":
            stand()
    else:
        draw()

def myblackjack(mycards, computercards):
    if 10 in mycards and 11 in mycards:
        print(computercards)
        print("BLACKJACK\nYOU WON!")
    else:
        hit_or_stand = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass: ")
        if hit_or_stand == "y":
            hit()
        elif hit_or_stand == "n":
            stand()


#Now, if I call the function called "myblackjack", the game starts and the dance between the functions takes place
myblackjack(mycards, computercards)


while True:
    keep_playing = input("Do you want to play another game of BlackJack? Type 'y' if that's so, otherwise type 'n'. " )
    if keep_playing == "y":
        clear()
        print(ascii.logo)
        mycards.clear()
        computercards.clear()
        cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]

        # here we draw our cards
        mycards = [random.choice(cards), random.choice(cards)]
        print(f"Your cards are: {mycards} current score:{sum(mycards)}")

        # here we draw the dealer's cards, both public and secret one. we only show, of course, the public one
        dealers_1st_card = random.choice(cards)
        computercards = []
        computercards.append(dealers_1st_card)
        computercards.append(random.choice(cards))
        print(f"Dealer's first card is: {dealers_1st_card}")
        myblackjack(mycards, computercards)
    else:
        break
```

I used a "hand-made" clear function, which works, but it doesn t clear the console the way a clear function in replit, for example, would do.

Comment: try using `os.system('cls')`  or if you are in Linux  `os.system('clear')`   (don't forget to `import os` at the beginning of your code)

Answer (score 1):

(I couldn't get `ascii.logo` to work for me. So I removed it)

You can use `os.system('cls')` for windows or `os.system('clear')` for mac/linux.

This is that implemented into your code,

**Import**

```
import random, ascii, os  # You can use commas to compact module imports

#print(ascii.logo)
```

**New Game Code**

```
while True:
    keep_playing = input("Do you want to play another game of BlackJack? Type 'y' if that's so, otherwise type 'n'. " )
    if keep_playing == "y":

        os.system('cls') #  <<< Windows version

        #print(ascii.logo)

        mycards.clear()
        computercards.clear()
        cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
        # here we draw our cards
        mycards = [random.choice(cards), random.choice(cards)]
        print(f"Your cards are: {mycards} current score:{sum(mycards)}")

        # here we draw the dealer's cards, both public and secret one. we only show, of course, the public one
        dealers_1st_card = random.choice(cards)
        computercards = []
        computercards.append(dealers_1st_card)
        computercards.append(random.choice(cards))
        print(f"Dealer's first card is: {dealers_1st_card}")
        myblackjack(mycards, computercards)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: well thanks, but it just prints another logo and all that beneath the game, instead of deleting everything from above and going from beginning. same on the Chix solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate I don't quite understand?

Answer (score 0):

Use a syscall to clear the console.

```
from os import system, name
def clear():
 
    # for windows
    if name == 'nt':
        _ = system('cls')
 
    # for mac and linux(here, os.name is 'posix')
    else:
        _ = system('clear')
```

[source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clear-screen-python/)

Comment: `_ =` is unnecessary just  `system('cls')` would work, Or simply `clear = lambda : system("cls" if name ="nt" else "clear")`